# Django date sorting issue with null values

Tags: python, django, datatables, django-pagination

Ok so i am using Django with eztables for ajax and pagination with jquery datatables. I think there must be some issue with the way django-eztables sorts dates with null values. If there are dates everything works fine, but when it starts to get to the rows with null dates the pagination gets weird. Some of the rows will be the same on the next page and some will be be the correct next rows for that page. This behavior only happens when i am sorting on that column.

Has anyone ever come across a similar problem like this? 
I had the idea of setting the models default value to a really low date, then overriding it when the table is rendered. but still having it in the DB for sorting and stuff, but this seems pretty hacky. Does python/django have some kind of minimum date constant that i could use for this? Or some other clever trick?

Comment: How did you sorted this, Is it on database layer or application layer?Please show code you tried.

Comment: You shouldn't be sorting on a field which has null values... filter them out from result before sorting

Comment: Thanks @SachinGupta I don't know why that never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

I took @SachinGupta advice and just performed a filter before sorting

```
object.exclude(object__in_progress_date__isnull=True).order_by(order_by)
```

Thank you!